# Extra colon in all silver and gold badges tooltip

Tags: bug, badges, tooltips

Just noticed this in the  [badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges): (two examples)

> [image] [image]

It's in all sites, not just here on Meta. Bronze tooltip is OK.

After checking it appears that the tooltip for all silver or gold badges, anywhere, got extra colon:: can you please fix this? ::)

Comment: This was reported the other day as well, let me find the dupe. Bronze badges are fine, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters didn't find in quick search, maybe should have searched deeper... :(

Comment: Yeah, "need checking" is pretty obscure.

Comment: I found it by searching for `[bug] [badges]` and sorting by newest.